# How to display the translated value of a boolean field when viewing a translated page?

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n

I have this problem with translation of a custom checkbox (boolean) field. To be specific, I'm able to translate everything but the options (Yes / No) that are shown on node view page.

I have the modules `locale`, `i18n_nodes`, and `i18n_fields` enabled, and translation strings imported (with corresponding context and to appropriate textgroup), and default language set to English. The translation shows correctly everywhere but on node view where it's still untranslated.

The content type is custom and is created via hook_node_info() and it's fields via field_create_field, and field create_instance.

---

BTW: I don't need translation of the content (every node will always have just one language and should be accessible regardless of what language the user has selected) but only of the user interface (descriptions, titles, ...). So if there's a simpler way to translate my custom fields and content types, please let me know.

---

Screenshot proofs that I've done everything I could:

Settings:
[image: Language settings]
[image: Field settings]
[image: .po file that is uploaded to appropriete textgroup (field)]
[image: An edit from translate option that shows .po is loaded]

Edit page:
[image: Everything is correctly translated on edit]

View page (note the only string that is in English but should be in Czech and should be Aktivni)
[image: Active is not translated]

Comment: That's odd. Have you tried translating the string with [Localization Client](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_client)?

Comment: @othermachines tried that but it didn't work with fields at all... (it showed circa 50 % of field related strings on page) and of course if found nothing for "Active"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try what's mentioned in [Comment #1](https://www.drupal.org/node/1762488#comment-6425074) of [issue # 1762488](https://www.drupal.org/node/1762488), i.e:

> ... visit 'Manage Display' and switch from "Default" to "Default translated".

Comment: Thanks for the accept! Looks like that was the missing piece of your i18n 'puzzle' ... Oh well, multilanguage sites, so much things to know and remember to make it work ... Anyway, I slightly enhance the title of your question also, to ake it more accurate, ok?

Comment: Yep, that looks better and thanks for the info. I wouldn't have found out about that myself :).

Comment: "Merci" (oeps, no French here ...: thank you) ... To be honest, when I first saw your question, it occured to me that I never ran into such (detailed) translation issue. So I learned from it myself also, for new time I have a similar field ... Note: I might soon "investigate" http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A17790+is%3Aq